# Abort execution of parsim

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulink, matlab-guide, matlab-app-designer

For the use case of being able to abort parallel simulations with a MATLAB GUI, I would like to stop all scheduled simulations after the user pressed the Stop button. 
All simulations are submitted at once using the [`parsim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/simulink/slref/parsim.html) command, hence something like a callback to my GUI variables (App Designer) would be the most preferable solution.

Approaches I have considered but were not exactly providing a desirable solution:

- The [Simulation Manager](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/simulink/slref/simulationmanager-app.html) provides the functionality to close simulations using its own interface. If I only had the code its Stop button executes...
- `parsim` uses the [Simulink.SimulationInput](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationinput-class.html) class as input to run simulations, allowing to modify the [`preSimFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2017b/simulink/slref/presimfcn.html) at the beginning of each simulation. I have not found a way to "skip" the simulation at its initialization phase apart from intentionally throwing an error so far.

Thank you for your help!

---

*Update 1*: Using the `preSimFcn` to set the the termination time equal to the start time drastically reduces simulation time. But since the first step still is computed there has to be a better solution.

```
simin = simin.setModelParameter('StopTime',get_param(mdl,'StartTime'))
```

---

*Update 2*: Intentionally throwing an error executing the `preSimFcn`, for example by setting it to

```
simin = simin.setModelParameter('SimulationCommand','stop')
```

provides the shortest termination times for me so far. Though, it requires catching and identifying the error in the `ErrorMessage`of the [`Simulink.SimulationOutput`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationoutput-class.html) object. As this is exactly the "ugly" implementation I wanted to avoid, the issue is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using 17b or later, parsim provides an option to 'RunInBackground'. It returns an array of Future objects.

```
F = parsim(in, 'RunInBackground', 'on')
```

Please note that is only available for parallel simulations. The Simulink.Simulation.Future object F provides a cancel method which will terminate the simulation. You can use the fetchOutputs methods to fetch the output from the simulation.

```
F.cancel();
```